# Pass JSON object that contains Array with session.Storage

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, session

I'm trying to pass a JSON object using the function session.Storage, in order to keep the object browsing between pages. The JSON object looks like this:

`var shapeResult={"accuracy":
                            {"Syntactic":[], "Semantic":[],            "Data_Assurance":[],"Risk":[]},
                "completness":
                            {"Record":[], "Attribute":[],"Completness":[]},
                "consistency":
                            {"Integrity":[]}
                };`

In my page there's a function that first assigns some values to the empty arrays (as strings) :

```
var shapeResult={"accuracy":
                        {"Syntactic":[ID,EMAIL] "Semantic":[ID]}
                };
```

For each of these single value my Function will assign a 0, or a 1. In this way, accessing, for example the object, with this expression:

`shapeResult.accuracy.Syntactic`
 I would obtain either a 0, or 1.

Then I try to save it in the session storage trough

```
session.Storage.setItem('session_data',JSON.stringify(session_data_temp));
session_data_temp=JSON.parse(session.Storage.getItem('session_data'))
```

What I obtain from the sessionStorage is the first JSON object, without the added values in the array and the 0's and 1's.

What's the problem?

Comment: if you console.log out the session_data_temp before storing it into session storage do you see the 0s and 1s as you'd expect? Its not quite clear what you are trying to do, if you set item in the session storage using JSON.stringify(session_data_temp), it'll store that object fine. so it sounds like you are not setting the latest version of that object. - see answer, sounds like you should be using sessionStorage not session.Storage

Comment: If I console.log.out it before storing it into the session storage it's the object i need, with all the values. As soon as I get it from the session it does not contain the values I need. sessionStorage doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle with an example of it breaking?

Comment: @Marco did you checked my answer ?

Comment: @RohitJindal Yes, thanks. Unfortunately it does not work

Comment: Why it is not working ? can i know the reason

Comment: I'd like to know it too! I honestly do not understand where the problem is. But sessionStorage or session.Storage seems to give me the same result. An empty JSON file

Comment: I think we'll need a bit more info in order to help you. can you provide more code? or create a jsfiddle showing the problem you are experiencing. Without either I'm not sure we can help

Comment: if you open dev tools in chrome and open the application tab, can you see an entry in the session storage? Is it actually storing a value?

Comment: @MarcoBerlot I provided the working fiddle. you can run the code snippet. it is working fine

Comment: Thankss @RohitJindal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sessionStorage` instead of `session.Storage`

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gbh714e4/)**

```js
var shapeResult={"accuracy":
                        {"Syntactic":1}
                };
                
sessionStorage.setItem('session_data',JSON.stringify(shapeResult));
var session_data_temp=JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('session_data'));

console.log(session_data_temp);
```